# How to install xmlstarlet in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, xmlstarlet

I have a cygwin installed, and all the necessary packages for xmlstarlet installed. I have downloaded the xmlstarlet. I try to run it from cygwin with command "./xml.exe", it works. I just want to know, what should I do so that it can be run as a command inside Cygwin, so that I can start command like this "xmlstarlet 'argments'"

Comment: i just copy the xml.exe to cygwin\bin\, and now it works, but is it appropriate to do that?

Comment: I see no problems on doing that, mostly because, as you said, it worked, now I will do that too, thx! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question. You say first that you run it under Cygwin and it works, and then you ask how to run it under Cygwin

As long as the executable is somewhere in your `PATH`, you should be able to run it from any Cygwin shell, passing it arguments, just as you would under Linux, or any other Unix variant.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for windows.
You can download [the zip](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/download.php) that has the xml.exe CLI that you
can unzip it and then you have to set the folder where you unzip the files like environment variable for windows, then if you have and script and you call the tool using a command like "xmlstarlet 'argments' ..." you have to replace the word **xmlstarlet** by **xml.exe**, example "xml.exe'argments' ..." with this you can use the CLI from anywhere.